# Need ASN.1 specifications for M3UA protocol

Tags: ss7

I need to parse the buffer of m3ua protocol. In order to parse the same I will require asn.1 specifications for M3UA.

Kindly could anyone provide me the link for the same.
It will be a great help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this one:

> RFC 3332: Signaling System 7 (SS7) Message Transfer Part 3 (MTP3) - User
>   Adaptation Layer (M3UA)

https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3332.txt

Answer (score 0):

SIGTRAN's MTP3-User Adaptation Layer (M3UA) provides for the transport of MTP user protocols such as ISUP and SCCP.

Since you are inquiring about ASN.1 we can assume you are interested in one of the SCCP user protocols.  The first step will be to decode the Signaling Connection Control Part (SCCP).  See the ITU-T recommendations (http://www.itu.int/itu-t/recommendations/index.aspx?ser=Q) or your national variant (e.g. ANSI):

```
 Q.711-Q.719: Signalling Connection Control Part (SCCP)
```

In all likelihood the SCCP user protocol you are interested in is TCAP:

```
 Q.770-Q.779: Transaction Capabilities Application Part (TCAP)
```

The ASN.1 specification for TCAP is contained in Q.773:

```
 Q.773: Transaction Capabilities Formats and Encoding
 http://www.itu.int/itu-t/recommendations/rec.aspx?rec=4079
```

The TC user protocol you are most likely to be interested in is the Mobile Application Part (MAP).  The GSM/UMTS specification for MAP contains the ASN.1:

```
 3GPP TS 29.002 Mobile Application Part (MAP) Specification
 http://webapp.etsi.org/key/key.asp?GSMSpecPart1=29&GSMSpecPart2=002&Search=search
```